# $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n-1}\binom{n-1}{k-1}\frac{a^{n-k}b^k}{k}=\frac{(a+b)^n-a^n-b^n}{n}$

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, binomial-coefficients

In "[New properties for a composition of some generating functions for primes](https://arxiv.org/abs/1109.1683)", properties of generating functions are used to form a primality test, speaking specifically in example 1 the following equality appears:

$\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\binom{n-1}{k-1}\frac{a^{n-k}b^k}{k}=\frac{(a+b)^n-a^n-b^n}{n}, a,b,n\in\mathbb{Z}^+$

I don't doubt its veracity, but I don't see how to justify it (it's probably simple but I'm a bit lost).

Can someone guide me to prove this equality?

Comment: Note that $\binom{n-1}{k-1} = \frac{k}{n}\binom{n}{k}$.

Comment: The expression is simply a tricky modification of $(a+b)^n$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{aligned}
\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}{n-1\choose k-1}\frac{a^{n-k}b^k}{k}&=\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}{n \choose k}a^{n-k}b^k}{n} \\ &=\frac{\sum_{k=0}^{n}{n \choose k}a^{n-k}b^k-a^n-b^n}{n} \\ &= \frac{(a+b)^n-a^n-b^n}{n}
\end{aligned}$$